# Delete entries from json that are missing properties

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that contains about 100,000 lines in the following format:

```
{
"00-0000045": {
    "birthdate": "5/18/1975",
    "college": "Michigan State",
    "first_name": "Flozell",
    "full_name": "Flozell Adams",
    "gsis_id": "00-0000045",
    "gsis_name": "F.Adams",
    "height": 79,
    "last_name": "Adams",
    "profile_id": 2499355,
    "profile_url": "http://www.nfl.com/player/flozelladams/2499355/profile",
    "weight": 338,
    "years_pro": 13
},
"00-0000108": {
    "birthdate": "12/9/1974",
    "college": "Louisville",
    "first_name": "David",
    "full_name": "David Akers",
    "gsis_id": "00-0000108",
    "gsis_name": "D.Akers",
    "height": 70,
    "last_name": "Akers",
    "number": 2,
    "profile_id": 2499370,
    "profile_url": "http://www.nfl.com/player/davidakers/2499370/profile",
    "weight": 200,
    "years_pro": 16
    }
}
```

I am trying to delete all the items that do not have a `gsis_name` property. So far I have this python code, but it does not delete any values (note: I do not want to overwrite the original file)

```
import json

with open("players.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
    for x in json_data:
        if 'gsis_name' not in x:
            del x
print json_data
```

Answer (score 2):

You're deleting x, but x is a copy of the original element in json_data; deleting x won't actually delete it from the object that it was drawn from.

In Python, if you want to filter some items out of a collection your best bet is to copy the items you do want into a new collection.

```
clean_data =  {k: v for k, v in json_data.items() if 'gsis_name' in v}
```

and then write `clean_data` to a file with `json.dump`.

Answer (score 0):

Just create new dict without unwanted elements:

```
res = dict((k, v) for k, v in json_data.iteritems() if 'gsis_name' in json_data[k])
```

Since Python 2.7 you could use a dict comprehension.

Comment: Note that in Python 3, you would use `json_data.items()` instead of `json_data.iteritems()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `del x`, you are unassigning the name `x` from your current scope (in this case, global scope, since the delete is not in a class or function).

You need to delete it from the object `json_data`. [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) returns a dict because your main object is an associative array / map / Javascript object. When you iterate a dict, you are iterating over the keys, so `x` is a key (e.g. "00-0000108"). This is a bug: You want to check whether the *value* has the key `gsis_name`.

The documentation for `dict` shows you how to delete from a dict using the key: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

> *`del d[key]`*
>
> Remove `d[key]` from *d*. Raises a `KeyError` if *key* is not in the map.

But as the other answers say, it's better to create a new dict with the objects you want, rather than removing the objects you don't want.